# Handle on array setted to Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Folks, how I could 'catch' event when Backbone collection receives array with data? I need this to loop data and join some items on some conditions.
I have:

```
MyColl = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.Models.Movie,
    url: '/movies/start',
    events : {
        'then': 'show', // no one is calling
        'fetch': 'show'
    },
    show: function() {
        console.log(this.models);
        console.log(this.collection);
    }
});
```

And after fetching, when data is coming to collection, I need to do some magic stuff with data. Thanks for your answers.

I tried all of this, but nothing works..

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.Models.Movie,
    url: '/movies/start',
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(this.models);
        this.models.on('change', this.print, this);
     },
     events: {
        'add' : 'print',
        'change': 'print',
        'fetch': 'print'
      },
      print: function() {
         console.log(this.models + '!!!!'); // HOW TO CALL THIS, WHEN DATA IS COMING TO THIS COLLECTION AFTER FETCH ?
      }
 });
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but I think [`model.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) might be what you need. When you define `parse` on your model, it will be called with the data returned by the server, and you can manipulate the data at that time, before the model's attributes are set from it.

Comment: @Jordan, I need to catch moment when array from server just setted to collection

Comment: You probably want the [`"change"`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) event, which is fired any time models are added or removed from the collection.

Comment: @Jordan, please look at my updated question

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the connection from the server make sure `reset` is true:

```
col.fetch({reset: true});
```

Then watch for the `reset` event in the collection:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({

    events: {'reset': 'resetHappend'},

    resetHappened: function() {
        // whatever you need to do
    },

    // ...
```

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work. I tried Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.Models.Movie,
    url: '/movies/start',
    events: {
        'reset' : 'joinItems'
    },
    joinItems: function() {
        console.log('Now I could loop over the data');
        console.log(this.models);
    }
}); and then    movies.fetch({reset: true}).then(function() { ... });

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.Models.Movie,
    url: '/movies/start',
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('sync', this.joinItems, this);
    },
    joinItems: function() {
        console.log('Now I could loop over the data');
        console.log(this.models);
    }
});
```

And then:

```
movies.fetch().then(function() {
    var moviesView = new App.Views.MoviesView({collection: movies});
    $(document.body).append(moviesView.render().el);
});
```

That's what I needed. Thanks to all

Comment: this might work, but it is not the way you should do. The implementation is not optimal, You can use parse function to do the same and with you listening to any event..